# Get Intellij Idea to highlight incompatible compiler code?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-14

So we ran into an issue where `javac` can compile something but [eclipse can't](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480918). This may be a `javac` bug, but I suspect that neither side is going to fix the problem considering how long the [initial jdk bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8016207) report has been there.

> Error is: The method apply(Collection) in the type GenericsEclipseCompilerIssue.CollectionToString is not applicable for the arguments (Collection)

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GenericsEclipseCompilerIssue
{

    public static <T> Function<Optional<Collection<T>>, String> optionalCollectionToString(
        final Function<? super T, String> elementTransformer ) {
        return (collection) -> {
            return new CollectionToString<>( elementTransformer )
                .apply( collection.orElse( Collections.emptyList() ) );
        };
    }

    static class CollectionToString<E> implements Function<Collection<E>, String> {

        private final Function<? super E, String> elementTransformer;

        public CollectionToString( final Function<? super E, String> elementTransformer )
        {
            this.elementTransformer = elementTransformer;
        }

        @Override
        public String apply( final Collection<E> collection )
        {
            List<String> strings = collection.stream()
                .filter( Objects::nonNull )
                .map( elementTransformer::apply )
                .sorted( String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER )
                .collect( Collectors.toList() );

            return  strings.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get Intellij Idea to highlight this so that I don't accidentally introduce this issue?

Comment: Have you elected to switch to the Eclipse compiler in your normal day-to-day routine?

Comment: @Makoto other members of my team are using eclipse, in fact I'm the only one that doesn't. We could argue I should, but, I personally find it intolerable.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use the Eclipse compiler in IntelliJ?  I'm not going to go as far as say that you should use Eclipse, but you can make use of its compiler...

Comment: @Makoto I didn't know that was possible, I suppose in general (this might be why) I also don't know why you would... could be a solution if you wanted to provide an answer explaining that, and how.

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, it'd make more sense to do as the Romans do.  Since everyone is using the Eclipse compiler, you should be too (at least until that policy decides to change).

To do this, under Settings > Build, Execution and Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler, switch the setting from Javac to Eclipse.  Now, IntelliJ will make use of the Eclipse compiler to build your code.

Comment: so this is a decent answer but I just realized that it broke my debugger (can't see local variables), which is not an acceptable tradeoff (and yes I have the generate debugging info enabled)